# Mac OS X: Cancel VPN connection on password prompt breaks all VPN connection attempts until reboot

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, vpn

If I try to connect to a VPN and then at the user / password prompt I press cancel (for instance, when I accidentally select the wrong VPN), it cancels the attempt, and then any further attempt to connect to any VPN just fails and asks me to check my settings.

Any ideas?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: What type of VPN is it (L2TP, PPTP, Cisco IPSec, or something else)?  If it's one of the builtin ones, is there anything informative in /private/var/log/ppp.log (you can view it with the Console utility)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out that killing the process `/usr/sbin/racoon` forces the VPN system to reboot without having to restart the entire OS.

1. Open Terminal and run `sudo ps -ef|grep racoon`

   - Requires sudo
2. Identify the process number for `/usr/sbin/racoon` in the 2nd column of the following output (in this case, 289)

   `0   289     1   0   0:00.04 ??         0:00.07 /usr/sbin/racoon`

   `501   452   224   0   0:00.00 ttys000    0:00.00 grep --color racoon`
3. Run `sudo kill -9 289` to end the process

*UPDATED*:

Since the migration of services to `launchctl` I've found that the above solution is no longer reliable (although I don't think it's entirely useless yet). I often resort to the below however:

```
killall racoon
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.racoon
sudo launchctl start com.apple.racoon
```